# ipad UITableViewController full screen

Tags: ipad, uitableview, fullscreen

I am converting my app to run on the ipad.

I have a view which is a UITableViewController. How can I cause the table to fill the screen with excess space filled with a background color when the table isn't tall enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on the frame you give to the view controller. But most of the time I don't use an UITableViewController but just an UITableView. It's more simple to handle it to do things you want ^^

To fill the excess space you just need to set a backgroundColor to the superView. If it's because you have less cells, then you could try setting the color to the uitableview view and setting color to the cell.
Maybe if you could give us a screenshot it would be easier :-) (or some pieces of code ^^)

Good Luck !